# Uncaught type error :How to fix jQuery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing a web application with Python Flask. I need a jQuery script to make an autocomplete search field. I found this one:

https://github.com/LukasSliacky/Flask-Autocomplete

It works perfectly fine.

The problem is coming when I tri to integrate this feature in my existing template which include a lot of other CSS and JS scripts.

Here is my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/materialdesignicons.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/vendor.bundle.base.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/favicon.ico') }}">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-scroller">

     {{ form.autocomp.label }}: {{ form.autocomp }}

</div>



    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor.bundle.base.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chart.js/Chart.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/off-canvas.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/hoverable-collapse.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/template.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dashboard.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/data-table.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js')}}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.cookie.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
                }).done(function (data){
                    $('#city_autocomplete').autocomplete({
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 2
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>


</body>


</html>
```

When I try it, it shows some error console:

[image]

So after searching for solution, I tried to remove some of these jquery files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

, but I still have the same issue.

Does anyone knows how to fix my particular case?

Here is my Flask Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request
import json
from wtforms import TextField, Form

class SearchForm(Form):
    autocomp = TextField('Insert City', id='city_autocomplete')


@app.route('/_autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    return Response(json.dumps(list_result), mimetype='application/json')


@app.route('/testsearch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm(request.form)
    return render_template("search.html", form=form)
```

Comment: The error message says that `autocomplete` is not a function, not that `$` is undefined.

Comment: I saw the error message as I am the one who publish it here. Your comment doesn't help at all.  I know there is a conflict but when I try to remove some jquery, I still have the issue.

Comment: The problem in your question title (`$`) an the problem in the [picture of the error message](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are different. You'll find it easier to get help when you are clear and accurate in what you ask.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loads jQuery (an ancient, unsupported version of jQuery with known security problems in it, but jQuery none the less):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
> ```

This loads jQuery UI (also an out of date version), which adds the `autocomplete` plugin.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
> ```

So that that point `$('#city_autocomplete').autocomplete` should be a function.

You then load a bunch of other things and we only have the filenames to go on.

You imply that everything above was added specifically for this task so since you have:

> ```
>  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.dataTables.js')}}"></script>
> ```

… we can assume that one of the two previous lines already loads jQuery.

> ```
>     <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor.bundle.base.js')}}"></script>
> ```

… is the most likely candidate.

---

The *new* version of jQuery overwrites the one you added jQuery UI to so the `autocomplete` plugin goes away.

Don't load jQuery twice.

Load it once.

Load it first.

Then add jQuery UI to it.